# what is the behaviour of moving dot with 50% chance to go left or right?

Tags: probability, random-walk

If a dot is moving (from zero) left or right, by one, with 50% chance to go left or right - is it going to go to the +inf or -inf when it has infinite moves?

Comment: is there a reason why someone gave -1 to this question?

Comment: It is a symmetric random walk and it will, with positive probability, return to any state infinitely often.

Comment: If you are sure, why not post it as an answer? I am asking this because I remembered from school that we had a proof saying yes to this question, when learning probability, but it doesn't make to much sense when you compare moving left/right to the (for example) flipping coins - we expect it will be around zero (equal number of heads/tails)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the simple symmetric [random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) on the integers. It is well known that this walk is *recurrent*, and so visits every point infinitely often with probability one. In particular, it has probability zero of converging to either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Proofs can be found [here](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/), or in most introductory textbooks on random processes.

Comment: On the other hand, it has probability zero of staying bounded.

Comment: @Gerry: A fact which is included in the statement that the random walk *visits every point infinitely often with probability one*.

Comment: However the waiting time for it to return to any given state has infinite mean.